# Android Prepressed State of View

Tags: android, view, touch

I am working on an app that will let the user trigger a sound by touching multiple views. Unfortunately, the android goes into a prepressed state (of 120 millisec I think)  before recognizing a real press and play the sound. This is a significant problem for my application as I need the sounds to be triggered without that lag. Is there any known way to avoid the prepressed state of android? can you suggest another approach to solving this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and not a button, I would think that it would be fairly responsive.

Comment: I tried that but it seems like it always goes into a prepressed state before entering a pressed state and trigger the action of playing the sound. I read a little bit of the prepressed state and apparently it is meant for detecting short taps

Comment: And you're playing the sound on `ACTION_DOWN`?